# Accessing and updating In-Memory data via URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, http

I'm currently learning about creating a server using the node.js framework Express.

Using the code below I understand how to access or GET the list of students or GET 1 student by name, however I'm not sure how to DELETE a student by id. I tried the localhost:4000/students/1 and it doesn't work, what should the URL it look like?

Same questions for the app.put method. If I type localhost:4000/students/James/art/50 I simply get an error saying "cannot get localhost:4000/students/James/art/50" so it never actually uses the put method.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

let students = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'James',
    classes: {
      computer: 95,
      art: 92
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Leeroy',
    classes: {
      computer: 95,
      art: 92
    }
  }
];

app.get('/students', (req, res) => {
  res.json(students);
});

app.get('/students/:name', (req, res) => {
  res.json(students.find((student) => student.name === req.params.name));
});

app.put('/students/:name/:class/:grade', (req, res) => {
  const student = students.find((student) => student.name === req.params.name);

  if (student) {
    student.classes[req.params.class] = parseInt(req.params.grade);
    res.status(201).send(`Student ${req.params.name} was assigned a grade of ${req.params.grade} in ${req.params.class}`);
  } else {
    res.status(404).send('Student not foun');
  }
});

app.delete('/students/:id', (req, res) => {
  const student = students.find((student) => student.id === req.params.id);

  if (student) {
    students = students.filter((obj) => obj.id !== req.params.id);
    res.status(201).send('Student was deleted.');
  }
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port 4000');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a tool in order to test requests different to GET, I recommend [Postman](https://www.postman.com/product/api-client/) there you'll be able to test the DELETE, PUT and POST requests